# Are ResNets used for something else than image recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

ResNets are widely used for image recognition tasks.
I wonder, are there any other application areas where they proved to be also very efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Resnets are neural network architecture which makes use of the Identity Connection, which helps to protect the network from vanishing gradient problem. They are used to make the deep networks more efficient. Regarding their use case, they can be used for speech recognition, audio classification, video categorisation/classification and in conjuction with other models LSTMs to solve other use cases.